# I am trying to submit an object that contains some data and a file from the client app to the API app using ASP.CORE 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have tried to submit an object from client app to an API which contains some data and a file, but I failed to do so.

Here is the code:

**(1)** The model:

```
public class ABC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

**(2)** The client app controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ABC aBC)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aBC), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using (var response = httpClient.PostAsync(BaseURLManager.BaseUrl + "ABCs", content))
            {
                var apiResponse = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                aBC = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ABC>(apiResponse.Result);
            }
        }
        return View(aBC);
    }
```

**(3)** The API controller

```
    // POST: api/ABCs
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ABC>> PostABC([FromForm] ABC aBC)
    {
        _context.ABC.Add(aBC);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetABC", new { id = aBC.Id }, aBC);
    }
```

Could any one provide me a working code, I am using ASP.NET Core 5.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is the error you are getting. which part of this code is not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the "object" you expect? Please clarify

Comment: I would like to create an ABC object that contain all data including the file and send it to the API. I got no error, instead the API end point (PustABC) receive the ABC object with null values.

Comment: can you check in app controller if stringcontent is correctly serialized ?

Comment: Yes it is correctly serialized, and I have checked the object before posting it to the API endpoint (it contains the correct data), but it arrived at the API endpoint with null value

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the FromForm attribute inside the api method, you should send request in formdata instead of json format.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new("https://localhost:7105/api/")
        };


        var path = $"{_hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath}test.json"; 

        var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);


          var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "PostABC");

          var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
                {
                    // file
                    { new StreamContent(stream), "File", "test.json" },

                    // payload
                    { new StringContent("1"), "Id" },
                    { new StringContent("bbbb"), "Image" },
                    { new StringContent("ccc"), "Name" }
                 };

        request.Content = content;

         var re = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

Result:

[image]